# Bootstrap grid not behaving properly in angular2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular2-template

I am doing some Bootstrap grid in my HTML, but it is not working properly, I am doing it in angular2, and I am new to it, but I do not think that because of it, Bootstrap natural property is getting interrupted.

my code is below:

```
<div class="container  index-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="dashboard-icon ">
                    <img src="./assets/img/icon/Merchant_onboarding_03.png" alt="MerchantBoarding" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                <div class="dvIndexInnerHeader">
                    Merchant Boarding
                </div>
                <p>
                    Some Text
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 " >
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="dashboard-icon">
                    <img src="./assets/img/icon/Agwnt_Management.png" alt="AgentManagement" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                <div class="dvIndexInnerHeader">
                    Merchant Boarding
                </div>
                <p>
                    Some Text
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

but it is coming:

[image]

The outer columns are working fine, but the internal are collapsed. The circular div and the text one is collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you're trying to obtain but why have these nested column definitions?

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
```

You should streamline those rows/columns, you can't do direct nesting (f.e., columns should be the only direct children of rows). Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** nest Bootstrap columns directly inside other Bootstrap columns.

Instead, always use `.row`+`.col` combinations for nesting.

A Bootstrap column must have a `.row` as a parent.